# cannot use phone (type string) as type int in assignment

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I have an error "cannot use phone (type string) as type int in assignment",
how to fix this?

I use in github.com/gin-gonic/gin and github.com/jinzhu/gor

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type Employees struct {
    gorm.Model
    Phone int
}

func (idb *InDB) CreateEmployees(c *gin.Context) {
    var (
        em models.Employees
        result gin.H
  )

  phone := c.PostForm("phone")
  em.Phone = phone

  result = gin.H {
        "result": em,
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
}
```

Comment: A phone number is not an integer. Why are you declaring it as one? How is `(555) 555-5555` an integer value? You can do math operations on an `int`. How do you do that with a phone number? How do you multiply a phone number by 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value in `PostForm` are all strings. You should declare `phone` as string type, or convert the phone number from string to integer. Like `strconv.Atoi` or `strconv.ParseInt`

```
phone := c.PostForm("phone")
phoneNumber, _ := strconv.Atoi(phone)
em.Phone = phoneNumber
```